# nuget package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: nuget

I created nuget package yet while

```
PS C:\Users\vicky\Documents\ThreadBasedJobQueue\Testnuget> dotnet add package abhi.TaskQueueLib --version 1.0.0
  Writing C:\Users\vicky\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp44DF.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'abhi.TaskQueueLib' into project 'C:\Users\vicky\Documents\ThreadBasedJobQueue\Testnuget\Tes
tnuget.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\vicky\Documents\ThreadBasedJobQueue\Testnuget\Testnuget.csproj...
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/abhi.taskqueuelib/index.json
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/abhi.taskqueuelib/index.json 1139ms
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/abhi.taskqueuelib/1.0.0/abhi.taskqueuelib.1.0.0.nupkg
info :   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/abhi.taskqueuelib/1.0.0/abhi.taskqueuelib.1.0.0.nupkg 1424ms
log  : Installing abhi.TaskQueueLib 1.0.0.
error: Package abhi.TaskQueueLib 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package abhi.TaskQueueLib 1.0.0
 supports: root (Root,Version=v0.0)
error: Package 'abhi.TaskQueueLib' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\vicky\Documents\ThreadBasedJobQueue\Testn
uget\Testnuget.csproj'.
```

Comment: Can you post your csproj/nuspec or however you packed this nupkg? 

There's some issues with your authoring here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue in lib folder i had to make folder by framework Name and then had to pack.
Un knowing i was keeping my Dll in Lib Folder

please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Answer (score 0):

The following documentation has the answers you are seeking:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks

Irrespective of whether you target one framework or multiple frameworks, you should create the ‘framework’ folder under the lib directory and then put the dll into that framework folder. This folder for the target framework is called Target Framework Moniker or TFM in short. List of all the allowed TFMs for NuGet is captured here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks